# Using Q to return secondary query in node with express and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, q

New to node, As I am cycling through a roster of students, I need to check and see if a teacher has requested them for tutoring.

I realized I can't just do this:

```
var checkRequest = function(id){
    var value = '';
    roster.query('SELECT * FROM teacher_request WHERE student_id ='+id, function(err, row){
        value = row.length;
    }
    return value;
}
```

After a bit of digging around promises looked like a great solution, but if I simply return the deferred.promise from the checkRequest function, all I get is an object that says [deferred promise] which I can't access the actual data from. (Or have not figured out how yet)

If I follow along with their api and use .then (as illustrated in the getRow) function, I am back in the same problem I was in before.

```
function checkRequest(id) {
  console.log(id);
  var deferred = Q.defer();
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM teacher_request WHERE student_id ='+id, function(err, row){
        deferred.resolve(row.length);
    });
  return deferred.promise;
}

var getRow = function(id){
    checkRequest(id).then(function(val) {
        console.log(val); // works great
        return val; //back to the same problem
    });
}
```

The roster needs to be able to be pulled from an external API which is why I am not bundling the request check with the original roster query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to get away from synchronous coding when using node.js. Just put you logic, that depends on `checkRequest()` inside the callback.

Comment: what function calling getRow(), you don't return that way.

Comment: As I am looping over each student in the roster in jade to print out their info, getRow() is being called inside that loop.

Comment: ok. don't do it one by one. read Q.all.

Answer (score 0):

From the stuff you posted, I assume you have not really understood the concept of promises. They allow you to queue up callbacks, that get executed, when the asynchronous operation has finished (by succeeding or failing).

So instead of somehow getting the results back to your synchronous workflow, you should convert that workflow to work asynchronous as well. So a small example for your current problem:

```
// your students' ids in here
var studentsArray = [ 1, 2, 5, 6, 9 ];

for( var i=0; i<studentsArray.length; i++ ) {
  checkRequest( i )
    .then( function( data ){
      console.log( data.student_id );

      // any other code related to a specific student in here
    });
}
```

or another option, if you need all students' data at the same time:

```
// your students' ids in here
var studentsArray = [ 1, 2, 5, 6, 9 ];

// collect all promises
var reqs = [];    

for( var i=0; i<studentsArray.length; i++ ) {
  reqs.push( checkRequest( i ) );
}

Q.all( reqs )
 .then( function(){
   // code in here
   // use `arguments` to access data
 });
```

Comment: So looking at your top option, if I execute that code I need to wait until all students have been checked before rendering my view. If I try to render after the for loop I am back in the say problem with async. How do I wait until the for loop is done to render my view?

Comment: @RyanY Like I wrote, if you need all data at the same time (eg. to render some output), use the second option with `Q.all()`.